# Debug symbols for KMail 5.7.3 on Kubuntu 18.04.03 LTS

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, debugging, kmail

In which package can I find the debug symbols for KMail 5.7.3 on Kubuntu 18.04.03 LTS?

Apport is not able to find them and `apt-get search` also does not give the required package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual with debug packages you have to follow [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug Symbol Packages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages):

```
# add ddebs repositories
echo "deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs) main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-proposed main restricted universe multiverse" | \
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list

# add GPG key
sudo apt install ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring

# update package lists
sudo apt-get update
```

and then install any debug package with *`-dbgsym`* suffix.

For your case:

```
sudo apt-get install kmail-dbgsym
```